# How to URL Rewrite on tomcat running behind Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, url-rewriting

I searched google many time, but unable to find a good answer.
I have `tomcat` running behind `Apache` linked via `mod_jk` on my `CentOs VPS`.
I want to rewrite urls.

I already tried [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).
It is working fine in my offline `tomcat` in Win7 PC
But not working on online VPS.

Is there any way to rewrite urls in `tomcat` running behind `Apache` (`Mod_JK`)

I have some jsp files in my APP and some of them are dynamic.

Comment: What error do you run into when using `UrlRewriteFilter` on the CentOs server? And log entries of interest you could add to the question?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /index.html, and i unable to acess /rewrite-status

Comment: Try adding your rewrite config to the question.